# If $P$ and $Q$ are square matrices such that $P^2$ is similar to $Q^2$, then is $P$ similar to $Q$.

Tags: linear-algebra

If $P$ and $Q$ are square matrices such that $P^2$ is similar to $Q^2$, then is $P$ similar to $Q$.  First since we know that $P^2$ is similar to $Q^2$, I Know we need to start with $P^2=S^{-1}Q^2S$.  My first question to make sure, I don't square the other two matrices do I?  How am I going to go about getting rid of the squares.

Comment: If $P=-Q$ then $P^2=Q^2$ - compare determinants in odd dimension.

Comment: The reverse is true. If $P$ and $Q$ are similar then $P^n$ is similar to $Q^n$ $ \forall n \in \mathbb N $

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure this claim is true? Here's a counterexample:
$$P=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix} \quad \text{and} \quad Q=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Or even $[1]$ and $[-1]$ ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Super!! Why didn't I think of that? :-)

Comment: Great example, Hagen!

Comment: Is just says IS P  similar to Q, so I am assuming that it may or may not be true, but still wanted to go about proving either way (true or false), Hence why I was going to start just with the definition of similar and work from their until I can conclude whether or not it is true.  So I am assuming it is is false by the answer, but how would I still prove it?

Comment: @andemw01: To prove that an "if-then" claim is false, all you need is provide at least one counterexample.